# Laravel - Yajra Datatables Exception Message: Trying to get property of non object

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I am a beginner of laravel. I want to join some of the tables and getting it displayed in datatables, I am using yajra datatables. I have four tables which are Schedule, Trip, BusTransport and BusConductor. The issues that I facing right now is I wan to display Schedule in a blade view,  I want to get *trip_id* from **Trip Table**, *bus_id* from **BusTransport Table** and *bus_conductor_id* from **BusConductor Table**. I able to display the data for Trip and BusConductor but I keep getting an error for one of the field from BusTransport. It shows me that **DataTables warning: table id=example - Exception Message: Trying to get property 'bus_code' of non object**.         Can anyone help me to spot my problem? Thanks and appreciate.

**Trip Table**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('trip', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('trip_code')->unique();
            $table->string('trip_origin');
            $table->string('trip_destination');
            $table->date('depart_date');
            $table->time('depart_time');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**BusTransport Table**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bus_transport', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('bus_code')->unique();
            $table->string('bus_number_plate');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**BusConductor Table**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('bus_conductor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('bus_conductor_name');
            $table->string('bus_conductor_contact_number');
            $table->timestamps();
        })
```

**Schedule Table**

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schedule', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('schedule_code')->unique();
            $table->bigInteger('trip_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('bus_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('bus_conductor_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('schedule', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('trip_id')->references('id')->on('trip')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('bus_id')->references('id')->on('bus_transport')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('bus_conductor_id')->references('id')->on('bus_conductor')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Trip Model**

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'trip';
    protected $fillable = [
        'trip_code',
        'trip_origin',
        'trip_destination',
        'depart_date',
        'depart_time'
    ];

    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
    }
}
```

**BusTransport Model**

```
class BusTransport extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'bus_transport';
    protected $fillable = [
        'bus_code',
        'bus_number_plate'
    ];

    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
    }


}
```

**BusConductor Model**

```
class BusConductor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'bus_conductor';
    protected $fillable = [
        'bus_conductor_name',
        'bus_conductor_contact_number'
    ];

    public function schedule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
    }
}
```

**Schedule Model**

```
class Schedule extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'schedule';
    protected $fillable = [
        'schedule_code',
        'trip_id',
        'bus_id',
        'bus_conductor_id'
    ];

    public function trip(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Trip::class);
      }

      public function busTransport(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BusTransport::class);
      }

    public function busConductor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BusConductor::class);
    }

}
```

**Ajax request for Schedule datatables**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var table = $('.table-striped.first').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('schedule.list') }}",
            columns: [{
                    data: 'schedule_code',
                    name: 'schedule_code'
                },
                {
                    data: 'trip_code',
                    name: 'trip_code'
                },
                {
                    data: 'bus_code',
                    name: 'bus_code'
                },
                {
                    data: 'bus_conductor_name',
                    name: 'bus_conductor_name'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: true,
                    searchable: true
                },
            ]
        });
```

**Schedule Controller**

```
    public function schedule(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Schedule::with('trip', 'busTransport', 'busConductor')->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('trip_code', function($row){
                return $row->trip->trip_code;
             })
             ->addColumn('bus_code', function($row){
                return $row->busTransport->bus_code;
             })
             ->addColumn('bus_conductor_name', function($row){
                return $row->busConductor->bus_conductor_name;
             })
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light editRecord">Edit</a>';

                $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light deleteRecord"><i class="far fa-trash-alt btn-outline-danger"></i></a>';

                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['trip_code', 'bus_code', 'bus_conductor_name', 'action'])
            ->make(true);
        }

        return view('admin.schedule', compact('trips', 'busTransports', 'busDrivers', 'busConductors'));
    }
```

Comment: try this  ->addColumn('bus_code', function($row){
                return $row->bus_transport->bus_code;
             }) and do same with busConductor

Comment: Hi @HuzaifaQidwai thanks for comment. It seems like not work for me. I am thinking of issue for my Schedule Model and BusTransport Model. Because I am just using the same logic for my Trip and BusConductor, there are no any issues for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in your Schedule Model

```
public function busTransport(){
  return $this->belongsTo(BusTransport::class, 'bus_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Wow bro it works! Can you explain and tell me why it is needed to add 'bus_id', 'id' at the last of the code? Thanks!

Comment: Syntax of belongsTo method is return $this->belongsTo(BusTransport::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

If you do not define the foreign key so the function goes to BusTransport model and find bus_transport_id but it is not present so that's why 
we need to define foreign key because function does not know.
If foreign key were 'bus_transport_id' so we don't need to define

Comment: Oh. So isit the field ''bus_id' from Sechdule table, I change it become 'bus_transport_id', I dont define the foreign key for it is okay right? Because as u say that the BusTransport model will find bus_transport_id. And it is present.

Comment: Yes that's great

Comment: Big thanks to you bro @Kashan Baig , u helped me a lot ! <3